# Pandas groupby out of memory

Tags: pandas, memory-management

I am adding a column to a dataframe calculating the number of days between each previous date for each of the customers with the following formula but I end up with out of memory

```
lapsed['Days']=lapsed[['Customer Number','GL Date']].groupby(['Customer Number']).diff()
```

The dataframe contains more than 1mln records

Customer Number is an int64 and I was thinking to run the the above statement withing ranges of numbers but I do not know if this is the best aproach

Any suggestion?

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us why you want this, and describe the output you want based on a simple example. In other words, a [MCVE].

Comment: On the surface nothing looks wrong with your code, one approach would be to use `dask` which can be used as an out-of-memory extension to pandas. That being said I am quite surprised that you get an out of memory error with only 1 million rows? Unless your memory is full of other stuff or your data is very wide

Comment: I have 128 GB or Ram  but I end up with out of memory, not sure if I can assign more memory to pandas.